# JHipster Spring Boot executable war config not recognized

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to experiment with a JHipster 4.3 app using Hazelcast.  I have a setup of 3 Linux/CentOS7 VMs, each with latest 8 131 java/jdk on them.  I build my war file for -Pprod and deploy to a dir at:

```
/var/jhiphaze/jhiphaze-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I have set this up as a service using systemctl.  I am able to start | restart | etc.

I now have a need to debug into the application and would like to start the app up in debug mode.  I read in the Spring Boot docs that I can place a file of the same base name with the extension of ".conf" and Spring Boot executable script will read the settings in the conf and start the app up with that.  So I have a file:

```
/var/jhiphaze/jhiphaze-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.conf
```

with the following line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y"
```

This has no effect on the run of the war, it starts up fine but does not listen and the console out indicates that the app is not listening on 8787 (or any port).

I also tried on my windows workstation, simply running from cli using:

```
java -jar jhiphaze-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

in the project /build dir with the jhiphaze-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.conf placed in the same directory.  It is ignored there as well.  The same argument in the conf file work at the cli:

```
java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y jhiphaze-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

works fine, pauses and waits for me to connect.  Note that I used `suspend=n` for most of my attempts as I did not want the service start to fail while waiting for debugger to connect.

How can I get the executable war to recognize its partner .conf file?